# Starting a windows service on remote machine in different domain

Tags: c#, windows, service, restart

My PC is in Domain A and a remote server in Domain B, I want to restart a service on server from my PC using c# or any other language or script.

Notes:

1. I am connected to the server via VPN that means i can manually RDP the server and can manually restart the service.
2. I am not able to access services on server using connect to other computer under action button from local services window.
3. I have admin rights to the server.
4. I can't(not allowed) add any component to server.
5. I have different set of credentials for Remote machine

Comment: This question might be better suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first try the `sc` command to make sure you're able to start that service remotely using the current permissions and credentials. If that works, take a look at `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`.

When you say you're an admin on the remote machine, I'm assuming that means you're logging in with different credentials. I don't believe either of those will allow you to use alternate credentials -- i.e., the commands will execute with Domain A privileges and those privileges are most likely insufficient for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Using ServiceController I can access (stop/start/ restart) services on machines in my domain but not in Other domain.

I have a different set of credentials for the other domain. I need to use these credentials to do any thing on remote machine manually(using RDP), but don't have any idea how this can be done using a windows form(without using RDP tool in .net).

Comment: @user1675935: I don't know if this will work and I don't have an environment where I can test it out... but have you tried using the `runas` command to launch your program? I can't locate online doc, but I believe it would be something like `runas /noprofile /netonly /user:<user>@<domain> <program>`.

Comment: Brenda It worked, I tried displaying all services in server, I have not tested to restart or stop a service but I think it should also work.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use a batch file? I usually use something like this:

```
NET USE \\computername\IPC$ /U:domainname\username password
SC \\computername START service
```